# Remover objetos da memória

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, winforms, linq

Tenho um `DataGridView` no meu projeto e um *timer* com *refresh* de 5 segundos. Percebi que o sistema estava sobrecarregando a memória, pois cada vez que listava os dados anteriores permaneciam na memória. Esse é o código que uso para listar:

```
Using (DBEntities db = new DBEntities())
{
      Dgv_Os.Datasource = null;
      List <OS> ostecnicos = (from o in db.OS select o).toList ();
      Dgv_Os.Datasource = ostecnicos;
}
```

Quais métodos para otimizar o código deixando o sistema mais leve?

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 2):

@user18748, não há muita coisa para otimizar uma consulta simples como esta.
Mas você pode tentar setar as seguintes propriedades:

```
db.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
db.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;
```

Caso em algum momento você precise chamar o SaveChanges(), não esqueça de fazer o seguinte:

```
((IObjectContextAdapter)db).ObjectContext.DetectChanges();
db.SaveChanges();
```

Como é citado no link abaixo, talvez seja interresante usar um BindingList:
http://madgeek.com/articles/leaks/leaks.en.html

```
List <OS> ostecnicos = (from o in db.OS select o).toList();
var bindingList = new BindingList<OS>(ostecnicos);
var source = new BindingSource(bindingList, null);
Dgv_Os.Datasource = source;
```

Comment: @user18748, editei a resposta para adicionar mais um prossibilidade.

Answer (score 2):

Não há como otimizar o trecho apresentado. Ele me parece muito adequado. O .Net se encarregará de liberar a memória quando for possível e necessário e você não precisa se preocupar com isto nestes caso. Pelo menos por este trecho. Pode até ser que outros trechos tenham problemas e não estejam permitindo que a liberação da memória.

Tenho até minhas dúvidas se a memória realmente está sobrecarregada, se você usou métodos confiáveis para determinar isto.

Talvez você tenha um volume de dados muito grande sendo carregado. Aí é outro problema.

Será que você precisa do *refresh* mesmo? Isto pode não ser a melhor forma. Mas mesmo fazendo isto cada vez que `ostecnicos` receber um novo objeto, o anterior estará livre para ser removido da memória quando o *garbage collector* desejar.

Usar o Entity Framework não é a forma mais adequada de tornar o sistema leve. Não que isto vá mudar muita coisa também mas você certamente nem cogita a possibilidade de não usá-lo.

Comment: O problema e que a memoria so esta sendo liberada com o fechamento do form, e o refresh de 5 segundos e necessario, pois o sistema é exibido em uma televisão para que os técnicos visualizem as os.

Comment: Ainda não me convenceu que a memória não está sendo liberada. Prove que ela não está. Prove que ela está acumulando em cada *refresh*. Continuo dizendo que o *refresh* não deve ser necessário. Este *site* me informa de novidades acontecidas nele que podem me interessar sem fazer *refresh* de qualquer tipo.